# Quarkus reactive messaging rabbitmq Connector with client certificate authentication

Tags: java, rabbitmq, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I would like to use the [Quarkus RabbitMQ Connector](https://quarkus.io/guides/rabbitmq-reference) to connect to a RabbitMQ Broker (Queues). The customer requires peer verification and client certificate authentication (instead of username/password). Unfortunately, I could not find an example of how to configure the client certificate.

In the Quarkus description, I found that he Vert.x RabbitMQ client can be customized (https://quarkus.io/guides/rabbitmq-reference#customizing-the-underlying-rabbitmq-client). I have the server certificate (where the RabbitMQ broker is running) as .crt and the keyfile as .key file. I also have the client certificate as a .pem file with the cert chain und the encrypted private key included.

```
------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
CERT  
-----END CERTIFICATE-----  
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
CERT   
-----END CERTIFICATE-----  
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
CERT  
-----END CERTIFICATE-----  
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----  
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Does anyone have experience with client certificate authentication and RabbitMQ?

I am currently not sure if the client certificate authentication works with Quarkus and the RabbitMQ connector. For the underlying vert.x client, I can only configure a truststore (https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rabbitmq-client/java/#_jks_trust_store_option). I set there the server certificate file and the password. Or should I create a own keystore with the server certificate and the client certificate included? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

### TLS Connections Without Peer Verification

You ***DO NOT*** need the server's private key! That would defeat the purpose of the server keeping it a secret.

If your RabbitMQ server or a TLS-terminating proxy uses a self-signed certificate, add the following configuration to your RabbitMQ client:

```java
PemTrustOptions trust = new PemTrustOptions().addCertPath("./tlc/ca.crt");
RabbitMQOptions options = new RabbitMQOptions()
    .setSsl(true)
    .setPemTrustOptions(trust)
    // ... other configuration options
```

Ensure that `./tlc/ca.crt` contains the public key (certificate) of the CA that signed the server certificate.

Try to make this work first before proceeding to client certificate authentication and peer verification.

### Enabling Peer Verification

To enable peer verification, provide the RabbitMQ client with the client's private and public key:

```java
PemKeyCertOptions keycert = new PemKeyCertOptions()
    .addCertPath("./tls/tls.crt")
    .addKeyPath("./tls/tls.key");
RabbitMQOptions options = new RabbitMQOptions()
    .setSsl(true)
    .setPemKeyCertOptions(keycert)
    // ... other configuration options
```

Here, `./tls/tls.crt` is the public key, and `./tls/tls.key` is the private key of your client certificate.

Ensure RabbitMQ is configured for [peer verification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#peer-verification-configuration). If your RabbitMQ server doesn't handle TLS traffic directly, consider configuring it at a higher layer (e.g., if behind HaProxy or Nginx).

For self-signed client certificates, inform the server (RabbitMQ or TLS terminating proxy) about their trustworthiness. Detailed steps for establishing this trust are beyond this post's scope.